# Char pointer storing address of int type data

Tags: c, pointers

Experts here I want to know that what's actually happening in this program. Because here the pointer is of `char` type and `var1` is of integer type.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char *ptr;
    int var1;
    ptr=&var1;
    *ptr=495;
    printf("\n%d %c",var1,var1);
    *ptr='495';
    printf("\n%d %c",var1,var1);
}
```

When I tried running this program, these are the warnings that I got-

```
v.c:6:4: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 ptr=&var1;
    ^
v.c:7:6: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 *ptr=495;
      ^
v.c:9:6: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
 *ptr='495';
      ^
v.c:9:6: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

And the output of this program is-

```
239 �

53 5
```

Here I don't understand that why is it saying data overflow.

My analysis of the program-

As pointer is of character type and as size of `char` is 1 byte, so pointer will only point to the base address of `var1`. And hence value stored in the first byte of `var1` will be the output. As the other 3 bytes won't be accessed by the pointer.

So I think in 1st `printf` 239 is printed as it is stored in the first byte of `var1` and � is printed because `%c` means a character whose ASCII value is 495 which isn't possible.

And in 2nd `printf` 495 is a character constant. But by 53 and 5 is printed.

I don't understand. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: `var1` is an `int`.  Its address has type `int *`, not `char *`.  You need to declare it to be `char` if you want a compatible address.  And `'495'` doesn't make sense as a character constant, at least not for assigning to a `char`.

Comment: *ptr='495'; is undefined behaviour ... It is compiler dependent so looks like the compiler is only taking '5' from '495' and it is assigning to *ptr.

Comment: Actually here I am trying to experiment that what will happen if I store the address of int type data in char pointer.

Comment: improved the formatting, especially of the compiler-warnings (for better understandability)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to point to an integer variable using a character pointer.

Pointer declaration needs to know which data type it is intended to point to. As it will be needed while dereferencing it. (How much bytes of data to be read from the memory?)

Here you are telling the compiler that the pointer points to 1 byte (char) and actually trying to point to integer (4 or 2 bytes); hence the errors. Also, '495', is multi character string.